# Writing an php associative array to a text file

Tags: php, mysql, fwrite

i want write an mysql_fetch_assoc(which returns an associative array) values to a text file,
though i want to get the output in a manner like below

```
ID => 17
CODE => 4
Value => 59559
```

it just gets printed like follows

```
17
4
59595
25
0
```

so this is the code that im currently using to get the result, can anybody help me on this

```
$query = "CALL pro_details($ID, '$start', '$end', $limit, $pos);";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
        $myFile = "debug.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        while($stringData_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                foreach ($stringData_2 as $string) {
                    fwrite($fh, $string);
                    $stringbreak = "\n";
                    fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
                }
                $stringbreak = "----------------\n";
                fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
        }
        fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about trying

```
foreach ($stringData_2 as $index => $string) {
    fwrite($fh, $index.'=>'.$string);
    $stringbreak = "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
}
```

Comment: Darren and roulie you guys replied first and both answers works... i dont know which answer to accept :P.. u have posted aanswers on exact time

Answer (score 4):

Change your `fwrite()` call to this:

```
foreach ($stringData_2 as $key=>$string) {
    fwrite($fh, $key ." => ".$string);
    $stringbreak = "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
}
```

Comment: Darren and roulie you guys replied first and both answers works... i dont know which answer to accept :P.. u have posted aanswers on exact time

Comment: @user3584871 go with roullie, he posted before mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while($stringData_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
               array_walk( $stringData_2 'displayData');


        }

...

function displayData($item, $key)
{
     fwrite($fh, "$key." => " . $item . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In foreach loop you can get both the key and values of an array

```
foreach($variable as $key => $value) {
    // so that u can print both the keys and values
    $key ---> ID,code,Value
    $value ---> 12,4,59559
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

You can solve like this

```
while($stringData_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach ($stringData_2 as $key=>$string) {
         fwrite($fh, $key.'=>'.$string);
         $stringbreak = "\n";fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
    }
   $stringbreak = "----------------\n";
   fwrite($fh, $stringbreak);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using serialize and unserialize?

```
 $array["key1"]="value1";
 $array["key2"]="value \"with\" quotes";
 $array["key3"]="value3";

 $tx=serialize($array);
 echo "<LI>serialized:".$tx;

 $test=unserialize($tx);
 foreach($test as $k=>$v) echo "<LI>rebuilt array:[$k] = [$v]";
```

returns

```
serialized:a:3:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";s:19:"value "with" quotes";s:4:"key3";s:6:"value3";}
rebuilt array:[key1] = [value1]
rebuilt array:[key2] = [value "with" quotes]
rebuilt array:[key3] = [value3]
```

so therefore you can do the following:

```
file_put_contents($fn, serialize($array1));
.
.
.
$array2=unserialize(file_get_contents($fn));
```